# Format a RAM disk with no drive letter by using `Format-Volume` cmdlet

Tags: powershell, format, ramdisk

### Background

I have a RAM disk created with ImDisk Toolkit. The drive letter is "R". I can access the RAM disk properly (`Get-ChildItem R:` shows directory entries properly).

I want to format the RAM disk in my powershell script (it runs a benchmark) without administrator authority. So I want to refrain from using `format` command because it needs administrator authority to execute.

### Problem

When I tried to format the RAM disk with `Format-Volume` PowerShell cmdlet, I got the following error:

```
PS C:\> Format-Volume -DriveLetter R
Format-Volume : No MSFT_Volume objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'R'.  Verify the value of the
property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Format-Volume -DriveLetter R
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (R:Char) [Format-Volume], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_DriveLetter,Format-Volume
```

And I found the RAM disk seems to have no drive letter from PowerShell (with `Get-Volume`).

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName     FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining     Size
----------- ------------     -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------     ----
E                            Unknown        Fixed     Healthy      Unknown                     0 B      0 B
C           Windows          NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    334.99 GB 475.7 GB
            Windows RE tools NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    504.46 MB   990 MB
```

I have tried to choose the RAM disk with `FriendlyName` property, but I couldn't access that property. `FriendlyName` seems to be not actual property (it is not listed with `Get-Member`). So I couldn't filter the result of `Get-Volume` and pass it to `Format-Volume`.

### Question

How can I specify the RAM disk to format with `Format-Volume` cmdlet that seems to have no drive letter with `Get-Volume`? Or, do I have to use `format` command rather than `Format-Volume` cmdlet (so I must have administrator authority) in this situation ?

### Edit

I found the RAM disk doesn't appear in the result of `Get-Volume`, `Get-CimInstance Win32_Volume` or `Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskPartition`. It appears only in the result of `Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk` like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk

DeviceID DriveType ProviderName VolumeName Size          FreeSpace
-------- --------- ------------ ---------- ----          ---------
C:       3                      Windows    510781288448  353026121728
E:       3
R:       3                                 1073737728    1056030720
Z:       3                                 3897664995328 3646232199168
```

Note that the RAM disk (R:) is shown as `DriveType 3` (Fixed disk).

I could get the object of the RAM disk (R:), but I got following error with `Format-Volume`.

```
PS C:\> $ramDisk = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq "R:" }
PS C:\> Format-Volume -Partition $ramDisk -WhatIf
Format-Volume : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Partition', because PSTypeNames of the argument do not match the
PSTypeName required by the parameter: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Partition.
At line:1 char:26
+ Format-Volume -Partition $ramDisk -WhatIf
+                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Format-Volume], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MismatchedPSTypeName,Format-Volume
```

### Edit 2

`Format-Volume -InputObject` also returns following error.

```
PS C:\> $ramDisk = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk | Where DeviceId -eq 'R:'
PS C:\> $ramDisk

DeviceID DriveType ProviderName VolumeName Size       FreeSpace
-------- --------- ------------ ---------- ----       ---------
R:       3                                 1073737728 1056030720

PS C:\> Format-Volume -InputObject $ramDisk -WhatIf
Format-Volume : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject', because PSTypeNames of the argument do not match the P
STypeName required by the parameter: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Volume.
At line:1 char:28
+ Format-Volume -InputObject $ramDisk -WhatIf
+                            ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Format-Volume], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MismatchedPSTypeName,Format-Volume
```

Comment: Re Edit 2: It's looking for a specific `CimInstance` subtype, if you will: `MSFT_Volume`, as reported by `Get-Volume` (the full ETS type name is `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Volume`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed at users forum that [ImDisk has no interface for Volume Mount Manager](https://sourceforge.net/p/imdisk-toolkit/discussion/general/thread/1dc454d620/). So there is no way to format the RAM disk made with ImDisk with `Format-Volume` cmdlet.

Note: I had also tried to format a RAM disk made with [Dataram RAMDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk). It has an interface for Volume Mount Manager, but `Format-Volume -DriveLetter S` eventually requires the administrator authority.

```
PS C:\> Format-Volume -DriveLetter S
Format-Volume : Access Denied
Activity ID: {1c815d1b-72f2-4432-b0e1-a33c96d2f539}
At line:1 char:1
+ Format-Volume -DriveLetter S
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Format-Volume], CimExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 40001,Format-Volume
```

It seems the `Format-Volume` cmdlet requires the administrator authority anyway.